# Box-Ljung Statistic and, standard errors of ACF and model fit statistics in SPSS

Tags: time-series, spss

I am just trying to fit a simple ARIMA(1, 0, 0) model in SPSS TSMODEL for 10 data points (90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 70, 98, 88, 65, and 60, representing 10 years of data). However, when I looked at the output, the standard errors for the ACF and model fit statistics, and the Box-Ljung Statistic are all missing. Can someone explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Here are some of the SPSS output.
[[image]]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6moN.jpg)
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ74P.jpg)
[[image]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9RTG.jpg)
[[image]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtdrC.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Ljung-Box statistic, 18 lags are used in its computation, so you need to have at least 19 time points in order to get that test statistic.

For the standard errors in the other output, you're getting standard errors for the Residual autocorrelation function for the model (your last output table). For the first two output tables, where the SEs are missing, this is because these tables are for comparing models when you fit models to multiple series. If you added a second series to the data, you'd see standard errors for the means in these tables.

In the dialogs for the Time Series Modeler (TSMODEL) procedure, on the Statistics tab, there are sections for Statistics for Comparing Models, and Statistics for Individual Models. The output for individual models is what you're getting in the last three output tables above, while the first two are from the output for comparing models.